# Class Interface functionality

Tags: c++

If I have the following code:

> ```
> class A_Interface {
>  public:
>     virtual void i_am_a() = 0;
> };
> ```

```
class A : public A_Interface {
 public:
    void i_am_a() {printf("This is A\n");}
};

class B_interface {
 public:
    virtual void i_am_b() = 0;
    // would like to run i_am_a()
};
class B : public A, public B_interface {
 public:
    void i_am_b() {printf("This is B\n");}
};

int main() {
    B BO;
    B_interface* BI = &BO;

    BI->i_am_b();
    // ******* WOULD LIKE TO RUN THE FOLLOWING ********
    BI->i_am_a();
}
```

What are my options to be able to run the class A member function from B_Interface Pointer?

I know that it is possible for B_interface to inherit A_interface as:

> class B_Interface : virtual public A_interface ...

```
class A : virtural public A_Interface ...
```

But that makes it impossible using GMOCK to the best of my knowledge to mock class B.  What are my options?

Thanks...

Comment: if GMOCK (is that google mockup?) is as limited as you stated, consider yourself lucky to have discovered this, and move on. don't let a testing helper tool decide the structure of your code.

Comment: I was wrong, GMOCK can handle this...

Comment: What a mess of inconsistent formatting, and typos.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `class B_interface` have:

```
void i_am_a()
{
     // throws if the object does not actually have A as a base
     dynamic_cast<A &>(*this).i_am_a();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was wrong, again :(.  So here is the answer code can be like this:

```
class A_Interface {
 public:
    virtual void i_am_a() = 0;
};

class A : virtual public A_Interface {
 public:
    void i_am_a() {printf("This is A\n");}
};

class B_Interface : virtual public A_Interface {
 public:
    virtual void i_am_b() = 0;
    // would like to run i_am_a()
};

class B : public A, public B_interface {
 public:
    void i_am_b() {printf("This is B\n");}
};
```

GMock can be like this:

```
class MockB : public B_Interface, public MockA {
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo, int(int));
}
```

This works for me in real application, but seems a little messy.